# how to pass $(this) object from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I think its very basic Object oriented javaScript related question. But I'm still very confused about it. I would like to pass $(this) object from 1 function to another. So that I can get the href attr of the link clicked.

Here my sample code

**HTML**

```
<a href="#testblah" class="test" rel="image">TEST</a>
<a href="#blahtest" class="test" rel="video">TEST</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", ".test", function () {

var $this = $(this);
var rel = $this.attr("rel");

if (rel == "image") {
    e.preventDefault();
    openImage($this);
} else if (rel == "video") {
    openVideo($this);
}
});

function openImage($this) {

var href =  $this.attr("href");
alert(href);
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine if you make your event handler accept an `e` argument: http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/19/

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right @AndrewWhitaker ! *bummer* I made a silly mistake!
just asking for an opinion is the above code best practice? I mean I defined  a var named $this and then used same name to call that object in other function? Should I use different name ? or it does not matter at all! 
 Thanks..

Comment: I would name the variable something a bit more meaningful like `link` or `anchor`. `$this` isn't very descriptive. Technically it does not matter though.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. `$this` is a very bad name for something, especially as `$` has no business being in a variable name in the first place.

Comment: tadman, it's good practice to stick $ on the start of any variable that contains a jquery object. Just you can keep track of which of your variables can have jquery functions called on them and which can't.

Comment: Instead of editing you question you should write your edit as an answer and accept it. This is the commonly accepted and perfectly valid way to mark your problem as solved.

Comment: Okay Christoph! I Followed your instruction! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question had 1 small syntax error please (check 1st comment on question)

Following is the code I ended up using.

```
$(document).on("click", ".test", function (e) {

    var anchor = $(this);
    var rel = anchor.attr("rel");

    if (rel == "image") {
        e.preventDefault();
        openImage(anchor);
    } else if (rel == "video") {
        openVideo(anchor);
    }
    });

    function openImage(anchor) {
    var href =  anchor.attr("href");
    alert(href);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the examples in the jQuery documentation [page](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You'll find that the *on* method applies to the selected elements, in the case of your code, it's the *document* object. To get the attribute that you want, jQuery is not necessary to wrap the element. Here's a JSBin [example](http://jsbin.com/ebumiv/1/edit). One more thing, try reemplace == with === to get type checking also. Hope it helps